# PowerBi - Weeknumber not in the correct order

Tags: powerbi

I'm new to PowerBi and i'm running into the following problem:

Weeknum + year are not shown in the correct order. See the following screenshots:

[image]

I've concatenate weeknumber with year based on a column called "PublishDate"

This is my dax query for weeknum:

```
 Weeknum = YEAR ( [PublishDate] ) & "" & WEEKNUM ( [PublishDate], 2 )
```

I do notice that 1 till 9 are not shown with a 0 infront of it. Could this be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the values are being sorted in alphabetical order, because they are of datatype text. So yes, the fact that '9' does not have a '0' in front of it, does cause your problem. You can solve this by changing the format of the WEEKNUM function like this (also you do not need `& "" &`):

```
Weeknum = YEAR ( [PublishDate] ) & FORMAT(WEEKNUM ( [PublishDate], 2 ),"00")
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with getting the '0' in the right place. Once you change the data type from text to a number, if that '0' in't there, it will be out of order as well.

I prefer editing the query and changing the data type from the beginning:
[image: edit query]

Finding the column that needs a data type change and modifying it there:

[[image: edit data type[2]]

You can change it from text to whole number.